# I wish to have a mapView in my relative layout which has imageView and TextView

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-relativelayout

To get a MapView, I would have to extend my class with MapActivity. When I try to do this, I get an error "Create MapActivity Class".

If I do not extend it with MapActivity and use Activity instead, I get the following Exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.strive.gostrive/com.strive.gostrive.EventDetailActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #168: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
```

I have made the required changes in the xml file, android manifest file. I have also included the google play services lib in my project. The target for both  google play services and my app is the same.

Need Help!!

Here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".EventDetailActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/eventDImg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/eventDEndDate"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/innershadow" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2D"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/eventDDateTV"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/eventDDateTV"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/eventDDateTV"
    android:text="-" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventDEndDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2D"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2D"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:text="End Date" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventDStartAge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/eventDEndDate"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3D"
    android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:text="frm" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4D"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/eventDEndDate"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/eventDStartAge"
    android:text="-" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventDAgeTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/eventDEndDate"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4D"
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:text="to" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventDTitleTV"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="Event Title"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventDDateTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eventDTitleTV"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:text="Strt Date" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1D"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/eventDTitleTV"
    android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/eventDPriceTV"
    android:text="$"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3D"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/eventDDayTV"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/eventDEndDate"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/eventDTitleTV"
    android:text="Ages:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventDPriceTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1D"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1D"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3D"
    android:text="Event Fee"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventDStrtTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eventDDayTV"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Strt Tym" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventDEndTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/eventDStrtTime"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/eventDEndDate"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:text="End tym" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventDVenueTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/eventDEndTime"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/eventDGender"
    android:text="Venue" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventDDayTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/eventDImg"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eventDDateTV"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:text="M Tu W" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventDGender"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/eventDDayTV"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/eventDDayTV"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1D"
    android:text="gender" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/eventDImg"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/eventDImg"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eventDImg"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="***************************"
        android:clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the activity

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class EventDetailActivity extends Activity{

MapView map;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_detail);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    int position =  bundle.getInt("position");

    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

    TextView txtEventName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.eventDTitleTV);
    TextView txtEventFee = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.eventDPriceTV); 

    TextView txtStartDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.eventDDateTV);
    TextView txtEndDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.eventDEndDate); 

    TextView txtStartAge = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.eventDStartAge);
    TextView txtEndAge = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.eventDAgeTV); 

    TextView txtDaysWeek = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.eventDDayTV); 
    TextView txtEventGender = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.eventDGender); 

    txtEventName.setText(EventModel.PREF_EVENTNAME); 
    txtEventFee.setText(EventModel.PREF_EVENTFEE);
    txtStartAge.setText(EventModel.PREF_EVENTSATRTAGE);
    txtEndAge.setText(EventModel.PREF_EVENTENDAGE);
    txtStartDate.setText(EventModel.PREF_EVENTSTARTDATE);
    txtEndDate.setText(EventModel.PREF_EVENTENDDATE);
    txtDaysWeek.setText(EventModel.PREF_EVENTDAYSWEEK);
    txtEventGender.setText(EventModel.PREF_EVENTGENDER);


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.event_detail, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Should you be using View class ``com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`` instead?

Comment: @harism Do you mean instead of activity class??

Comment: In your layout file, since Maps v2 ``MapView`` has been moved to ``com.google.android.gms.maps`` package. Not ``com.google.android.maps`` anymore.

Comment: @harism I am importing com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView in my activity.

Comment: But your layout file misses the ``.gms.`` part though I'm suspecting your layout inflating fails because of this.

Comment: @harism  you were right. I had missed .gms. in my layout file. Now I am able to get the view. But I am not getting any MapView in it. I am getting the rest of the layout components.

Comment: @Raghunandan I did. It did not work. Should I be adding anythin in my activity class??

Comment: check if you have all tags closed properly in the xml file

Comment: @Raghunandan It is properly closed.

Comment: I am not getting any error. My app runs properly. The map is not getting displayed in the MapView.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview ote: Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API has been officially deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012. This means that from March 18th, 2013 you will no longer be able to request an API key for this version. No new features will be added to Google Maps Android API v1. However, apps using v1 will continue to work on devices. Existing and new developers are encouraged to use Google Maps Android API v2.

Comment: I am using Google Maps Android API v2.

Comment: show us the activity code

Comment: @Raghunandan I have added the activity code

Comment: try extends MapActivity instead of Activity

Comment: I have tried that aswell. But as I have mentioned in my question, I get an error. It asks me to create a class MapActivity.

Comment: <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />  added this in manifest?

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes!! I have also included the google play services lib in my project. I have set permissions for internet and GRS in my manifest file.

Comment: Nothing more that i can think of. try generating a new key

Comment: How do I get a key for Debug mode? Any Idea?

Comment: You could use MapFragment instead. This way you don't need to extends MapActivity. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?#add_a_map

Comment: @Leaudro Thnx. It worked with MapFragment. But I was not able to run it on lower versions of android as the minimun sdk required is 11. How do I use it with the lower versions? like sdk-8?

Comment: check out my answer below :) Don't forget to accept the answer if it helps you ^^

Answer (score 0):

You could use MapFragment instead. This way you don't need to extends MapActivity.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?#add_a_map

To use with lower versions, you can use [SupportMapFragment](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment). To use this class, you must include the Android support library in your build path.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working Activity with a MapView inside a RelativeLayout.

For the map to appear, create a project at Google APIs, enable map API, create credentials, copy keys into your app at

```
src/debug/res/values/google_maps.xml
src/release/res/values/google_maps.xml
```

Update AndroidManifest.xml inside Application

```
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

<activity android:name=".MapActivity"/>
```

Or create an activity layout with a RelativeLayout and TextViews etc.  Use findViewById etc.

```
package au.com.derpapps.derpapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

public class MapActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback  {

    // Private variables

    private MapView mapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    // Activity methods

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        mapView = new MapView(this);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(200, 200, 200, 200);
        mapView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        relativeLayout.addView(mapView);
        setContentView(relativeLayout);

        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;

        mapView.onResume();
    }

}
```